# Duda Etiqueta en asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp

tengo esta funcion:

```
 if (this.IsValidPost())
 {
     if (gv.Selection.Count > 0)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < gv.VisibleRowCount; i++)
             {
                 if (gv.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
                 {
                     // relleno de objvacacion
                 }
             }

             // Update base de datos
             // Reload Data                   
             // mensaje informativo
         }                               

         VacationError:
             this.lblError.Text = msg;
             lblError.CssClass = "labelError";
 }
```

La función la entiendo, se lo que hace, el problema es que no entiendo la etiqueta "VacationError" no se que función tiene aquí dentro :S

podéis explicarme que hace la etiqueta "VacationError:" en este trozo de código asp? yo la reconozco de ficheros bath, pero aquí....

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No tiene ningun sentido.. parece que copiaron codigo de vb6.. y lo dejaron ahi...

Answer (score 1):

la clase `VacationError` debe ser una clase con la cual se esta controlando los posibles errores, si le das `control` + `F12` a la clase te llevara a su declaración o solo dando `F12` en la clase.

```
  VacationError:
             this.lblError.Text = msg;
             lblError.CssClass = "labelError";
```

`this.lblError.Text = msg;` - Posible mensaje de error

`lblError.CssClass = "labelError"` - posible Clase de css que se agrega el mensaje

Comment: Eh publicado la respuesta que se ve mas claro que si la pongo aqui xD

Comment: Si la respuesta aclara tu duda no olvides en marcarl. Gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

El .text y el .cssclass no hacia falta jeje pero muchas gracias =mente

La cosa es esa, no hay ninguna classe que se llame asi
Al dar F12, no me lleva a ninguna declaración porque no tiene

Al poner el mouse encima me dice: "No existe ninguna referencia a esta etiqueta"
Al dar en "mostrar posibles correcciones" se queda igual y no muestra nada

A lo que me refería es que eso yo lo entiendo como una etiqueta de un BATCH para hacer el GOTO.. pero en ASP.NET? sirve de algo, o mas bien era un "ELSE" que se han dejado de implementarlo al traerlo de otro lenguaje (bath como creo que es)

Gracias

Comment: Esto deberia ser una edicion a tu pregunta y no una respuesta. El campo respuestas es para poner respuestas. Mira los enlaces que te pase en el comentario a tu pregunta. Y elimina esta respuesta.

Comment: NO ES UNA EDICION A NINGUNA PREGUNTA
ES UNA RESPUESTA AL COMENTARIO QUE HAN PUESTO, QUE TAL SI NOS FIJAMOS MAS...

Comment: No es una respuesta a tu pregunta. El campo respuestas solo debe usarse para respuestas. Si queres dejar un comentario en la respuesta que te pusieron, lo pones ahi. Escribir todo en mayuscula se considera gritar, y solo trato de enseñarte a usar el sitio como corresponde. Esto no es un foro y hay reglas claras. Ni siquiera te tomaste el tiempo en leer el [tour] como para saber como funciona este sitio. Te recomiendo que lo leas.